# Excel not recalculating if formula until it's forced to

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a macro which generates a list from a spreadsheet, filters out things we need and don't need and formats it at the end. For filtering out information I am using a simple if formula which is inputted by my macro:

```
MyRange4.Formula = "=IF(M2<H2+1,""yes"",""no"")"
MyRange4.AutoFill Destination:=Formula3
```

When you run the macro, it is slowing it down a bit because it has to calculate for over 2000 lines, but it looked fine to me for a while, until we realized some of the lines we should have on the list are not there. When looking into it, I have filtered on the line we wanted, and the if formula was showing "no" which is obviously why it's not got excluded, but after 2-3 second the sheet recalculated and it's changed to "yes". Is there anyway I could force this to happen before the macro filters on the "yes" ones only so I am sure it's all correct?

Comment: There's a Calculate method for a range

Comment: It would be good to show some data and how you want to process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this do the trick for you:

```
'Above this line: First bit of your code untill calculating formula's
Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns("A:A").Calculate 'Change sheetname and column accordingly
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If
'Below this line: Second bit of your code, filtering the data
```